# How do I use css to set width to the end of the screen?

Tags: css

I'm working on a user style for a website.

There are different divs that are different spaces away from the left border.

I want it so the div ends at the end of the screen.

I thought about something like this

```
.class {
    width: 100%;
}
```

However, this doesn't stop at the end of the screen. This continues to go.

How can I make it so it doesn't matter how far away it is from the left side, it always ends at the ending at the right

Comment: Can you post a complete code example please?

Comment: There is no catch-all solution for what you are asking, we need to see your specific code.

Comment: Sounds like you have margins/borders/paddings you aren't accounting for.

Comment: What do you mean by "This continues to go"? Something that may be useful for you to know is that the width property acts on the width within the context of the parent container element.

Comment: It shouldn't "continue to go". Can you put the whole **css** here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to limit max width and height to screen size in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36253760/how-to-limit-max-width-and-height-to-screen-size-in-css)

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but try:

```
.class {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

100% is a dynamic width setting, the div will start on the left and end on the right.
It will use the entire width of the page when it has no parent to work with.
If the parent is 900 pixels, your .class div will also be 900 pixels.

I am assuming you are using a parent DIV width a static width which is exceeding the borders of the page.